# Add retention time to an hourly SQL job?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database backup running hourly between 7am and 7pm everyday, each file has a unique name. Is there a way that I can somehow add a 14 day retention time?

```
DECLARE @FileName AS VARCHAR(120)
DECLARE @Date AS CHAR(19)
SET @Date = CONVERT(CHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
SET @FileName = N'\\10.250.145.26\hfnfs\Trans\Hourly\South_RP' + @Date + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [South_RP] TO DISK =@FileName
```

File name Example   South_RP2012-06-26 11:00:00.bak

*Edit this is SQL sever 2008 R2

Comment: Please indicate somewhere that you're using MS SQL Server (there are lots of different kinds of SQL).

Comment: Do you want the backup command to automatically remove the backup after 14 days?  It doesn't have this functionality.  My hack for 7-day backups is to use the day-of-the-week in the name, rather than the date.  This overwrites the backups after 7 days.

Comment: I noticed this answer,but was unable to modify it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1895886/1483166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this using SQL Server.  Instead, I would set up a scheduled task that runs a batch file similar to the following:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
forfiles -d-14 -m*.bak -c"cmd /c del @PATH\@FILE"
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069/106302).  The way I wrote the batch file above, you'll want to place it in the same directory as the `.bak` files.  **Please, test it with `echo` first instead of `del`.**

To make it work, you'll need to get the `forfiles.exe` utility from [Microsoft's FTP site](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/y2kfix/x86/) and place it in your `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory.

If you *really* want to start this command from SQL Server, you can use [the `xp_cmdshell` procedure](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-file-from-sql-server-xp-cmdshell-ole-automation-procedures.aspx) to run the batch file that deletes old items.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a cron job/scheduled task to simply delete any backups that are >14 days old.